# How to refresh page when using navbar

Tags: html, angular

I have a navbar dropdown menu which includes some elements that should navigate to a page such as `homepage.com/championships/<region>`. Here is what the dropdown elements look like in HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'usa']">USA</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'world']">World</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'africa']">Africa</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'europe']">Europe</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'pan_american']">Pan American</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" routerLinkActive='active' [routerLink]="['/championships', 'asia_oceanic']">Asia Oceanic</a>
</div>
```

If I'm on `homepage.com` (not at `homepage.com/championships`) and I navigate to `homepage.com/championships/<any_region>` via one of the dropdown options, `ngOnInit()` is called, and can update my page with new information related to the url. However, If I'm already on `homepage.com/championships/usa` and I use the navbar to switch to `homepage.com/championships/world`, `ngOnInit()` Does not get called again. I see the URL is updated as expected, but for some reason the page does not refresh.

How can I ensure that when clicking on those navbar buttons the page refreshes so I can update some information on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnInit, You need to subscribe ActivatedRoute.paramMap. when the route parameter is changed then you will get a notification.

```
constructor(private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.doSomething(params.get('any_region'));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your .ts code as well.

In general, on first visit in OnInit you have to subscrtibe to [ActivatedRoute.params](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params). You will receive notification when route parameter is changed e.g. from "usa" to "world".

Also do not forget to clear this subscription on component destroy.